# Changing Hide/Show on click for multiple DIVs

Tags: jquery

first post here. I'm learning jQuery and have made a fixed menu that can pop out on click and also scrolls through DIVs. I'm really trying to improve my jQuery knowledge and I repeated my code a lot to make this work.

I'm looking for help so I could add an infinite amount of DIVs to the menu and it would still click through them. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's a link: http://jsfiddle.net/arbitel/peLkn/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.menubody:nth-child(1)').show('slow');
$('.menubody:nth-child(1)').hide('slow');

$('.floatingbarbutton').on({
    click: function () {
        if ($('.menubody:nth-child(2)').css('display') == 'block') {
            $('.menubody').hide('slow')
        } else if ($('.menubody:nth-child(3)').css('display') == 'block') {
            $('.menubody').hide('slow')
        } else if ($('.menubody').css('display') == 'none') {
            $('.menubody:nth-child(1)').show('slow')
        } else {
            $('.menubody').hide('slow')
        }
    }
});
$('.downarrow').on({
    click: function () {
        if ($('.menubody:nth-child(1)').css('display') == 'block') {
            $('.menubody:nth-child(1)').css('display', 'none')
            $('.menubody:nth-child(2)').css('display', 'block')
        } else if ($('.menubody:nth-child(2)').css('display') == 'block') {
            $('.menubody:nth-child(2)').css('display', 'none')
            $('.menubody:nth-child(3)').css('display', 'block')
        } else if ($('.menubody:nth-child(3)').css('display') == 'block') {
            $('.menubody:nth-child(3)').css('display', 'none')
            $('.menubody:nth-child(1)').css('display', 'block')
        }

    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.floatingbarbutton').on({
    click: function () {
        if($('.menubody').is(':visible')){
            $('.menubody').hide('slow');//if menu is visible then hide
        }
        else{
            $('.menubody:eq(0)').show('slow');//if menu is hidden then show first
        }
    }
});
$('.downarrow').on({
    click: function () {
        var i = $('.menubody:visible').index();
        var len = $('.menubody').length;
        var next;
        if(i >= 0){
            if(i == len-1){
                next = $('.menubody:eq(0)');//if last menu is visible then show first
            }
            else{
                next = $('.menubody:eq('+(i+1)+')');//show next menu otherwise 
            }
            $('.menubody:visible').hide();
            $(next).show();
        }
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/peLkn/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I updated the script for your downarrow code at this jsfiddle

```
var curDiv = 1;
var divCount = $(".menubody").length;
$('.downarrow').click(function () {
    $(".menubody:nth-child("+curDiv+")").hide();
    curDiv++;
    if (curDiv>divCount) { curDiv=1;}
    $(".menubody:nth-child("+curDiv+")").show();
});
```

It's far more efficient and can handle an infinite number of .menubody divs.

Comment: wow even better, that's really short and efficient. thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm sure this is a big rookie question, what are the plus symbols doing in +curDiv+ and curDiv++ ?

Comment: curDiv++ increments the value of curDiv by one.  And the +curDiv+ is concatenation to insert the value of the curDiv as the nth-child.